# Write a program that rewrites Russian letters from this file to a separate one new file, English letters in a different file

Tags: c++

The file contains both Russian and English letters and other characters. Write
a program that rewrites Russian letters from this file to a separate one
new file, English letters in a different file.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt"); //Opening the first file for reading
    std::string string; //Buffer string
    std::ofstream output("output.txt"); //Open the second file for recording
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        while (std::getline(input, string))  //Reading a string from the file (not yet EOF)
            output << string << std::endl;  //And write this line to the output file
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Tell me why it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't even compile...

Comment: @Vladislav Grin Can you translate the comments to English for us? I'm having a hard time following with Russian comments explaining

Comment: 1 - Opening the first file for reading  2 - Buffer string  3 - Open the second file for recording  4 - Reading a string from the file (not yet EOF)  5 - And write this line to the output file

Comment: You use `c` multiple times in `if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))` but you never declared nor assigned it anywhere. A compiler cannot ignore this. ;-) Additionally, if you read a string (which consists of multiple characters) and you want to check each character individually... isn't then something wrong with your nesting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through string character by character within the WHILE statement not before it.